# Whenever I change shorten the browser height on my landing page elements overlap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

For some reason whenever shorten the height of the browser, elements start to overlap.

I tried pulling it up in Firebug and troubleshoot it..but no luck. Hopfully one of you can help me!

EDIT:

Note Ever since I added the video its been doing this

HTML

```html
<section id="video">
    <video width="745px" height="414px" controls="controls" poster="video/video-poster.png">
        <source src="video/intro-video.mp4">
        <source src="video/intro-video.ogv">
        <source src="video/intro-video.webm">
        <iframe width="745" height="414" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Dhqnn3bA7LU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </video>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
#video {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 745px;
    width: 100%    !important;
    height: auto   !important;

}

video {
    max-width: 745px;
    width: 100%    !important;
    height: auto   !important;
}
```

Link: http://kmgp.us/clients/stackoverflow/

Huge thanks in advance!

**Here is what it looks like normally**
[image: Normal]

**And here is what it looks like when you shorten the browser height**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it sounds like you want your footer to be 'sticky', i.e. always on the bottom of the page. [This](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) css-tricks article outlines what you should do, but you should firstly move your `<footer>` outside of your `<div id='#container'>` and then apply the following CSS:

```css
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -32px; 
}
#container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
footer, #container:after {
 /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 32px; 
}
```

Also, as you pointed out, your background is also distorted. That's because you're applying your `box-shadow` to the `body` element. Try instead attaching it to your `#container`

Comment: Not what I needed.. ever seen I put in the <section id="video"> section ive been getting this issue.. so it must relate to that somehow..

Comment: Have you tried this? Your footer is overlapping because you're using `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`.

Comment: Yes but the background is still off position

Comment: Oh right, that's because you have your `box-shadow` attached to your body tag. 1 mo, I'll work out a fix. - see my updated answer.